# lsd_slam quick start problem

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, 3d-visualization, lsd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte. I install lsd_slam from [here](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam). I try tu run quickstart section. I install LSD_room.bag file. My file path is below :

```
 > home
    > fuerte_workspace
                   > lsd_slam
                        > lsd_slam_core
                        > lsd_slam_viewer
                   > sandbox
```

> rosrun lsd_slam_core live_slam image:=/image_raw  camera_info:=/camera_info

upper command require two input argument. But I don't know what I write them. How can I run this example?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212414/lsd_slam-quick-start-problem/) by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2015-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2015-06-29**:
I don't create LSD_room.bag. So I don't know that what it provides. Shouldn't I change image_raw and camera_info? Should I use this command directly?

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2015-06-29**:
Ok. It runs now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Run the commands exactly as listed; the supplied arguments should be correct for the bag file that they provide.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2015-07-11**:
I don't view color-depth map and point cloud. I can view only a red shape on viewer window.